# Trigger a method when the value of the global variable changes?

Tags: ios, xcode, global-variables

I have defined a global variable, where it get updates frequently with accelerometer data, So i want to stop the accelerometer updates as soon as it's above 0.9, But it doesnt work like this way

```
if([ACCEL sharedInstance].accelval > 0.90f){
[self.motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
}
```

Note: My accelerometer data gets updated, Do nothing wrong with the global variable thing! 
I call this inside `-(void)viewDidLoad`

Is there any other way to implement this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you use a property instead of a variable you can use [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to observe changes to it

Comment: Thank you for ur response. I was going through this article before this post, but since i m new to programming, i have less idea in getting it implemented! So i gave up. Anything flexible or if possible any other way ?

Comment: Hide the global variable and just have two global functions then `setAccelVal` and `getAccelVal` and then you know the only `accelVal` can be changed is through `setAccelVal` and you can put your conditional there

Comment: But, i want to implement through global variable, So i can learn this concept too, Do you have any practically implemented code? So that i can have a good understanding!